# How to uninstall V9 search engine?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, malware, utorrent

### Problem

I have installed UTorrent couple of days back and it silently (FYI, I unchecked the "Install V9 Toolbar") installed a **search engine** called V9.

It annoys me as it has been set as a default search engine for almost all browsers.

### What I have tried so far

1. I have tried uninstalling UTorrent.
2. Checked for something called "en.v9.com" in installed program list but no luck.
3. Tried to restore browser settings to default but no luck.
4. Changed Chrome default search engine to google and when I start a new Chrome it opens V9.

### PC OS

I Use **Windows 8**. I use only **Chrome**. I have installed Safari after this problem but the search engine is not affecting the new installations.

### Current workaround

I have deleted all the shortcuts from windows 8 and then go to Chrome installation path and I am running Chrome from there which is a current work around for me as of now.

I hope I could be clear in the details. Please let me know if you need to know anymore details. If you know anything about the solution Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

V9 virus is a typical browser hijacker.To remove V9 virus 
scan computer for malware with [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/products/malwarebytes_free/).

Malwarebytes Anti-Malware can be used to detect and remove additional and/or third-party malware from your computer system, including malware that may be responsible for symptoms of the V9 Search virus.

Perform full system scan.

Once the full system scan is complete, Malwarebytes may prompt a message stating malicious objects were detected. Select the malicious objects and click the Remove Selected button to completely remove the malicious files from your computer

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: I tried this and removed a registry entry that was bugging Chrome. Which didnot helped. I reinstalled it and it worked. Now the problem persists with IE.. Any amount of scan wont help. It just adds up new malwares to the AppData Temp folder.